# Sorting accented characters in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

When I run the command "select product_name from products order by product_name" the result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n92F5.png)

But, I would like to get this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1rna.png)

Note: The register "Água Oxigenada" does not need to be exactly in the first position, but together with the group of the letter "A", ignoring the accent.

Is it possible to configure MonetDB to order accented characters the way I expect (Brazilian Portuguese)?

Thank you!

Alexandre da Silva.

Answer (score 0):

You want a Brazilian Portuguese collation, which MonetDB doesn't support at the moment. It is on our TODO list.